# How do I grep for this? "my string -2.22 rest of string"

Tags: regex, grep

I have several sentences in a file in this format:

```
"my string -2.22 rest of string"
"my string -1.00 rest of string"
...
```

The numbers are all negative.

I want to grep for these sentences.

Right now I'm doing: `grep "my string -d\+ rest of string"` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: \d doesn't account for the decimal.

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using grep you can do:

```
grep 'my string [0-9.-]\+ rest of string' file
```

Or using extended regex:

```
grep -E 'my string [0-9.-]+ rest of string' file
```

`[0-9.-]+` matches 1 or more of any digit or DOT or hyphen

Note that this will allow multiple `-` or `.` in the number.

If you want to do precise matching then use:

```
grep -E 'my string [+-]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+ rest of string' file
```